# C to inline assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, hex, inline-assembly

i am supposed to to rewrite code from C to inline assembly. Code is transfering decimal numbers to hexadecimal.

Code i am supposed to transfer is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int a;
int main() {
char str[]="XX je hex\n";

if (scanf("%i", &a)==1) {

   /* This part of code i am supposed to transfer */

   int tmp = (a>>4)&0x0f;
   if (tmp <= 9) {
     tmp+='0';
   } else {
     tmp+='A'-10;
   }
   str[0]=tmp;
   tmp = a&0x0f;
   if (tmp <= 9) {
     tmp+='0';
   } else {
     tmp+='A'-10;
   }
   str[1]=tmp;
   /* Ends here */
   write(1, str, 10);
}
return 0;
}
```

So far i got this

```
asm volatile (

        "mov %a,%bx;"
        "shrw $4,%%bx;"
        "and $0x0f, %%bx;"

        "cmp $9,%bx;"
        "jle lessOrEq;"
        "jg greater;"

        "mov %bx,%str[0];"

        "mov %a,%bx;"
        "and $0x0f, %%bx;"

        "cmp $9,%bx;"
        "jle lessOrEq;"
        "jg greater;"


        "mov %bx,%str[1];"

        "lessOrEq: add '0',%bx; ret;"

        "greater: add 'A',%bx; sub 10,%bx; ret;"  

    :"=c"(str[0]), "=d" (str[1])
    :"a"(a),"c"(str[0]),"d"(str[1])
    :   
);
```

and i am getting this error: Invalid 'asm': operand number missing after %-letter.

Any idea what do i have wrong? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably a good idea to mention which line gives the error.

Comment: Sorry.. It gives error on the first line.. error: invalid 'asm': operand number missing after %-letter asm volatile (

Comment: Why do you write this as inline assembly? That's prone to all sort of errors like the ones you experience.

Comment: Instead, create an assembly file (`.s`) and write the whole code in assembly.

Answer (score 2):

In gcc inline assembly, register names need to be prefixed with **two** percent signs, which you actually do in your second and third instruction, but forget everywhere else. Just replacing `%bx` with `%%bx` should fix your error.

Comment: Thanks! I compiled it now succesfully, but it gives me Segmentation fault(core dumped) as output. Any idea why?

Comment: @a.vele I suggest you do some debugging work yourself (i.e. compile with debug flags and step through your program with a debugger) and once you have identified the line in which the segfault happens (or even better, its cause), see if you can fix it yourself and if not, open up a new question, because the problem this question is about is now fixed. I'll be glad to help you if you become stuck :)